# How to localize data annotations attributes using orchard .po files localization in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, orchardcms

I am using .po files for localization in asp.net core 2 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/portable-object-localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I am using it sucessfully inside views or controllers, but how to use it with DataAttributes in viewmodels.
Example:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RoleName is required")]
    [MinLength(1)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
```

Does anyone has any idea if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is being solved/solved already, reading this issue: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/1462

> "What do we do for the error messages? Do we convert them as [Required(ErrorMessage = "localized error message")] or should we use the default MVC error messages? (enabled via [Required])"

resolved as

> "Works in culture-settings branch by adding simply builder.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(); in OrchardCore.Mvc.Core Startup.cs file."

The PR was merged.

Comment: it's not completely resolved: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/2974